Is it illegal to allow (verbally) someone to do action that may kill them?
Here is example I am interested in: Bob has a cup that he knows is filled with poison and apple juice. He places the cup on a table. Another person Andrew asks Bob if he can drink that apple juice (Andrew doesn't know about the poison). Bob says he can. But Andrew decides not to drink it.
So the question is: Is what Bob did illegal? Considering that Andrew didn't drink. Can Bob be held liable if Andrew were to realise the truth?

If he thinks Andrew is likely to drink the poison, I think Bob could be liable for at least reckless disregard. If he actively encourages Andrew to drink it, it might even be attempted murder.

Did Bob intend to harm Andrew? Would Bob have had an opportunity to intervene if Bob had decided to drink it? Those critical facts see to be unclear.

Also, the title question and the body question are quite different. There is not a generalized duty of care to prevent people from doing things that could kill them. But Bob has more than a generalized duty of harm because Bob created the problem, he isn't a random third-party.

@Barmar reckless disregard would be ignoring Andrew, while saying anything towards allowing it that doesn't say it's poison would be encouraging.

@ohwilleke While you may not have to actively intercede in preventing someone from causing self-harm, what if Andrew asks him "Is it OK if I drink that?" or more simply "What's in the cup?" Surely Bob can't lie, can he?

@Barmar I agree that he can't lie. But if someone else poisons the cup and he says, "I'm not stopping you." that probably wouldn't be a crime.

I think a less contrived example than a cup containing poison is if Bob knows his bathroom lightswitch is faulty and might electrocute anyone pressing it, must he tell visitors e.g. Andrew?

The title and body of the question don't match. I expected something more akin to not telling a person entering train tracks to get out of there, when I clicked the question. That would obviously be vastly different from wilfully serving poison to someone who reasonably expects a drinkable beverage on a table. I don't think you could downplay that as "allowing (verbally)" when it's you who placed a cup of poison onto a table, and then confirmed it was "apple juice".

@natiiix there is no confirmation of what is inside the cup. And you are not serving poison. Bob just answers Andrew's question, he doesn't ask Andrew to drink it. I mean the cup can be even filled by someone else, although that is not part of my example.

I agree, the title could have been better

germany attempted murder
StGB §211 dictates, that Mord (~murder) can be triggered by an act that is (among others) insidious or dangerous to the public. Allowing an unwitting person to drink poison is insidious, putting poison out for consumption by anyone is dangerous to the public at large. Also, the BGH repeatedly affirmed, that depraved indifference to who might die triggers Mord: you do not need to want to kill a specific person, or even want to kill anyone, it suffices that you willingly accept that you could kill someone with a dangerous act and take no precautions. For example, driving a street race shows this depraved indifference, and as a result, running someone over during one is (attempted) murder.
As Andrew did not drink, we are at worst at the attempt under StGB § 22. The attempt is to be punished exactly the same as the successful deed.
As such, the prosecution in Germany can charge attempted murder for depraved indifference:

Andrew was unwitting and unsuspecting of poison, thus insidiousness is a given factor in case Andrew dies, which triggers Mord.
Bob acted insidious by not informing Andrew of the poison when he
told Andrew he could drink from the cup.
By allowing Andrew to drink from the cup, Bob offered Andrew the cup. So we have an act furthering the crime.
Bob also showed depraved indifference for Andrew's life in the act of allowing him to drink, and not informing him.

But since Andrew did not drink, we are at "Versuchter Mord". If proven, Bob is to be sentenced to life in prison because Mord only allows a sentence of life. Only in the case of an attempt, the court might show leniency and reduce the sentence somewhat, though it is unlikely with depraved indifference.

Not just Germany - AFAIK this would be attempted murder in every jurisdiction (or at least attempted Grievous Bloodily Harm)

probably "Bodily" rather than "Bloodily"

@BenVoigt — I like it better as “bloodily”.
